# How to say “everyone respects someone” and “someone respects everyone” in quantified logic?

Tags: logic

I’m having a hard time with this logic obviously isn’t my thing

Comment: You need a two-valued predicate like RESPECTS(x,y) which is TRUE if x respects y, FALSE if x does not respect y. See the similar functions on p. 4 of the PDF [The Syntax of Predicate Logic](https://www.bu.edu/linguistics/UG/course/lx502/_docs/lx502-predicate%20logic%201.pdf), along with subsequent discussion of how to use the universal quantifier and existential quantifier to express statements like "everything chased Socrates" or "Kermit kissed something" (there's an editing error in the PDF where they keep writing "Kermit chased" rather than "Kermit kissed" when using the predicate "KISS")

Comment: Also note in particular the two propositions 20a and 20b at the bottom of page 5 of the pdf, and their English translations--they both use a combination of the universal and existential quantifier with statements involving the two-valued predicate LOVE(x,y), you'll need to do something similar with RESPECTS(x,y).

Comment: Consider the binary relation **Is_Son_of(x,y)**: what do you think about "everyone Is_Son_of someone" vs "someone Is_Son_of everyone" ???

Comment: Thanks to @Hypnosifl link you can look at expression 33 and 35 therein. And then my comment below the answer below

Comment: I've changed 'some respects' to 'someone respects', which I take to be your meaning.  If I'm wrong, change the text back - except that 'some [people]' would need 'respect', not 'respects'.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming our quantifier ranges over human beings. 1:

```
∀∃xyRxy
∃∀xyRxy
```

or 2:

```
∀x∃yR(x,y)
∃x∀yR(x,y)
```

or 3:

Without assuming domain

```
∀x∃y((H(x) ∧ H(y)) → R(x,y))
∃x∀y((H(x) ∧ H(y)) → R(x,y))
```

or 4:

```
∀x∃y((H(x) ∧ H(y)) ∧  R(x,y))
∃x∀y((H(x) ∧ H(y)) ∧  R(x,y))
```

or 5:

if you want it as set−relations

```
R={(x,y): x ∈ H, y ∈ H* : H* ⊆ H}
```

or 6:

An even absurd version

```
H×H*, H* ⊆ H
```

or 7:

The absurd version of the even absurd version

```
((H×H*)^c)^c
```

or 8:

The absurd version of the vacous conditional

```
∀x∃y□((H(x) ∧ H(y)) → R(x,y))
∃x∀y□((H(x) ∧ H(y)) → R(x,y))
```

@Rusi-packing-up I hope this clears it up for you.

1. The first one says everything relates to something.
2. The second one says what the first says but in conventional notation.
3. The third one says, for everything there is something, if the two are H, then the first R−relates to the second.
4. The fourth one, the one YOU SUGGESTED, says for everything there is something, where the two are H, and the first R−relates to the second. If you think that's wrong, that's the one YOU suggested.
5. The fifth is as trivial as could be, if you can't read that, then I can't help you.
6. Sixth one is fifth but in the most compact sense.
7. Seventh just says to take the complement of the complement of what was stated in sixth.
8. Eightth is the fish−hook version of 3 since you happen to have a problem with "vacously true" conditionals.

Comment: If the H(uman) set is empty, the last line will be vacuously true. Intended? See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/ «Frege and Russell... formalized sentences of the form "Some A is B" and "Every A is B" as ∃x(Ax∧Bx) and ∀x(Ax→Bx), respectively.» 
Note this also respects de Morgan correctly generalizing ∧∨  to ∀∃ since Ax→Bx negates as Ax∧¬Bx

Comment: The issue is that the → in the last line should be an ∧ following SEP.  Also "some As are Bs" and "there exist A such that B" are synonymous. See more details [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Existential_quantification&oldid=1057306365)
Or see the @hypnosifl link examples I've highlighted below the question above. 
May help to see it as [Venn diagrams](http://tonyxzt.blogspot.com/2014/03/venn-diagrams-and-categorical.html) which would help show "some As are Bs" as more symmetric than "all As are Bs".

Comment: @Rusi-packing-up Please have a look, I made the answer to your taste.

Comment: You had one wrong formalization at start : ∃x∀y((H(x) ∧ H(y)) → R(x,y)). You've now added another wrong one : ∀x∃y((H(x) ∧ H(y)) ∧  R(x,y)). As for the "absurd" I've no idea what you're trying to do. Also the very first pair doesn't even parse by any standards... that I'm familiar with except perhaps something arcane like [de Bruijn indexes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index)

Comment: @Rusi-packing-up With all due respect, if you can't read simple statements, I don't think I can help you there. Regards

Comment: ∀x∃y((H(x) ∧ H(y)) ∧ R(x,y)) would imply that our domain of discourse only includes humans, but doesn't that go against your "without assuming domain" comment? If our domain of discourse includes some elements that are not human, so that (H(x) ∧ H(y)) would be false for such a non-human x, it seems like the statement "for every x which is human, there exists a human y such that x respects y" should be something like ∀x (H(x) → ∃y ((H(y) ∧ R(x,y)))

Comment: @Hypnosifl All good, if that's what you think.